# encoding wav file for sample

Tags: objective-c, c, encoding, ffmpeg

I saw one sample in encoding wav file,here is the sample

[sample for encoding](https://github.com/avshabanov/examples/blob/master/src/c/c-avcodec-audio/main-noise.c)

in this part of code have doubt:

/* encode a single tone sound */

```
    float t, tincr;



    t = 0;

    tincr = 2 * M_PI * 440.0 / c->sample_rate;

    for(i=0; i<2000; i++) {

        for(j=0;j<frame_size;j++) {

            samples[2*j] = (int)(sin(t) * 10000);

            samples[2*j+1] = samples[2*j];

            t += tincr;

        }

        /* encode the samples */
```

what is 2000 here,in basis of what we have to give this value,because of this i thing my encoding is not correct,any suggestion will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an arbitrary number of repeated 'frames' that make up the sample. In a different code path it constructs another type of wave form in a similar way and mentions `2000=>52sec`.

Comment: The code sample appears adapted from https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html wherein they allocate the same buffer size for 200 frames.

Comment: @noders yeah somewhere 200 ,somewhere 2000,there is not a equation to decide this number